# Cannot create many-to-many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

I connot create a many to many relation in ruby on rails. I always get an error when i try to save a new Glossary.

*"Glossary categories is invalid"*

This is my code:

```
def create(glossary_params)
  Glossary.transaction do
       @glossary = Glossary.new(name: glossary_params[:name],
                   identifier: glossary_params[:identifier],
                   description: glossary_params[:description],
                   private_glossary: glossary_params[:private_glossary])

      glossary_params[:categories_id].each do |c|
         @glossary.glossary_categories.build(category: Category.find_by_id(c), user: @user)
     end
  end
  @glossary
end
```

This is my Glossary Model:

```
class Glossary < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, presence: :true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :identifier, presence: :true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

  has_many :glossary_categories
  has_many :categories, through: :glossary_categories
end
```

This is my Category Model:

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :glossary_categories
   has_many :glossaries, through: :glossary_categories
end
```

This is my GlossaryCategory Model:

```
class GlossaryCategory < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :glossary
   belongs_to :category
   belongs_to :user
end
```

This is my glossary_category table:

```
create_table :glossary_categories do |t|
  t.belongs_to :glossary, index: true
  t.belongs_to :category, index: true
  t.integer :user_id
  t.timestamps
end
```

Comment: What columns does `glossary_categories` have? The problem is likely to lie there... if you could edit your question to include this, I reckon you'll get an answer pretty quickly :)

Comment: I edit my question, you could now see my create command for the table.

Comment: Hmm - looks fine (may want an index on `user_id` too). Are you using Rails 5? If so, could you try this again with `optional: true` added to your join table's `belongs_to` relations? I wonder if either `@user` or  `Category.find_by_id(c)` are nil and causing this. Let me know how this goes and I'll drop into an answer if it helps!

Comment: I use Rails 5. I try to add 'optional:ture' to my join table's. After that the glossary is saved in the database, but no GlossaryCategory. I try then ' @glossary.glossary_categories.create' but i get the exception _You cannot call create unless the parent is saved_ . How I can do this correct inside a transaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for my create method was:

```
def create(glossary_params)
   Glossary.transaction do
      @glossary = Glossary.create(name: glossary_params[:name],
                   identifier: glossary_params[:identifier],
                   description: glossary_params[:description],
                   private_glossary: glossary_params[:private_glossary])

      if @glossary.valid?
         if glossary_params[:categories_id].present?
            glossary_params[:categories_id].each do |c|
                @glossary.glossary_categories.create(category: Category.find_by_id(c), user: @user)
            end
         end
      end
   end
   @glossary
end
```